# I need to change the default Cypress fixtures and support folder

Tags: cypress

I have to test web app which has many user stories. So I need to have a common folders for fixtures and support form where I can call the fixtures and function files to other projects.
I have tried to update the Cypress.json file but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the fixtures folder and support file by setting `fixturesFolder` and `supportFile`, respectively. Your `cypress.json` should look like this:

```
{
  // rest of your `cypress.json` above...
  "fixturesFolder": "/test/cypress/fixtures",
  "pluginsFile": "/test/cypress/plugins/index.js"
}
```

For more information on these config options, check out the [docs for configuring file and folder locations in Cypress](https://on.cypress.io/configuration#Folders-Files).

If you've made changes to the correct file, your changes should show up in the [Settings Tab](https://on.cypress.io/configuration#Resolved-Configuration) in Cypress:

[image: Resolved Config]

Comment: Hi Zach, Thanks its working fine i have changed my Fixtures folder, but can we do same with Support folder aswell i tried moving Support folder to different folder, but getting below error

Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:
This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code. This is usually caused by:

A missing file or dependency
A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies

Comment: This should work. What have you set `supportFile` to?

Comment: The support "folder" is actually a path to a file, as in the name, `configFile`